# CMD Comparing Variables

Tags: date, variables, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I'm looking for a line that will check the time and date that would be supplied in the batch file to see if they are the same, and if they are then it would follow out a command.

Say, something that goes like `CHECK IF %DATE%=15/1/2014`

Thanks.

Comment: Explain a bit further.  If you are comparing `%date%` then what format does it show on the console?  Are you using the same format in your variable?

Comment: Yes. %DATE% would spurt out DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Nothing else?  Are you using the same format in your variable?

Comment: Nothing else. As I said, I'm looking for a command that would check if this and a supplied variable are the same.

Comment: Like if I set Variable1 = 12345,

I want to check if 12345 = Variable1

Comment: You will need leading zeros in your comparison date. eg if "%date%"=="15/01/2014" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a string comparison:

```
if "%variable1%"=="12345" (echo yes) else (echo no)
```

for a purely numeric comparison:

```
if %variable1% EQU 12345 (echo yes) else (echo no)
```